# How do I navigate with router.navigate conditionally?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I've got a table of entities. When you click a row you get to another page representing the entity (view page). The functionality uses `router.navigate`.

When the entity gets deleted you can't get to its view: you get 404 trying to open the url. There is no generic way call backend and find out if the entity still exists.

So I need some kind of conditional  navigation: if the link is not valid anymore I don't want to navigate to it (maybe show some modal and etc). How do I do it with Angular?

Thank you!

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @AdritaSharma no need for code, it is super-simple: on click a function is triggered that calls `router.navigate` - thta's it. sometimes it results in 404 and redirects me to 404 page but I don't need it. 404 routing is configured with `RouterModule.forRoot`

Comment: Maybe you could add a mechanism to prefetch data before navigating and only navigate when needed. [This is a good article showing you how to do it.](https://codeburst.io/the-right-way-to-prefetch-data-for-your-angular-components-pages-1e5cce099cee)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich Best way to handle 404 error is to have wildcard route `{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}`

Comment: @nitin9nair that's what I've got now globally. But I need to change this behaviour for my case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpClient` to see if your page returns status 200.

For example:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  this.http.get('/').subscribe(res => {
  }, error => {
    if (error.status === 200) console.log(error.status);
  })
}
```

This will always return error even with 200 status, therefore check for status 200 and then use your navigate. You probably need to unsubscribe once you are done.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried it! But eventually I'm getting 404 even for valid links (CORS issues I guess)

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich CORS should not be an issue as it's same domain. Look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-client-v6-vjmmg3

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich Use your app full `http://www.DmitrySenkovich.com` do not go for route only.

Comment: doesn't work, I've tried using an link with full http scheme with `http://localhost:4200/some_link`

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I suggest to create a stackblitz. Thanks